# Why can't I see my box in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've been told to use `position: relative` but when I go to view it in the browser it doesn't show up, please could you tell me why?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box
{
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    background: #366;
}
```

Comment: Does it show up when you change your div to: `<div id="box">&nbsp;</div>`?

Comment: What is the parent of the `div`? Your height / width will be set to 20% of that parent

Comment: If that's the only thing on the page then the page height is 0px. And 20% of 0px is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `html, body {height:100%}` to your CSS-File.

**http://jsfiddle.net/LGJH4/**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the CSS calculation. By default HTML page has no height.
So, your 20% for the height is just 0 as it is relative to HTML which has 0 height.

The option for you is either propose pixel height for #div or give a height to the whole document.

```
#box {
    height:100px;
}

or

html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
/*** Write your css here ***/
```

Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Pj6Ra/1/

Comment: Setting `100%` on the `body` only won't do anything, because it's context `html` still has no height. So you *need both*: `html, body {height:100%}`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, without a parent element with a defined height, a `%` height will result in `0px`. You'll need to use a different height unit, such as px or em. E.g.

```
#box {
    height:200px;
}
```

Interestingly, you could use `padding-bottom: 20%`, although that wouldn't give you the result you expect. The height is then 20% of the *width* of the viewport, rather than of the height.

Comment: In this context, % height has no *context*. It would be meaningful if there were a parent element with a set height, but normally that's not the case.

Comment: without a parent element - yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/LWtyS/)**

```
   html,body
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: while this gives a certain height to the div (the line height) this is not the intended `20%`.